# iOS: What's the difference between Push and Broadcast notifications?

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What are the general use cases for either?
Where in the app cycle do they fit in?
What are some of the advantages/ disadvantages of either?
Do they show up even if an app is "force closed"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @blue_zinc There are not Broadcast notification in iOS, if you mean Push notification with it. You can only send push notification to specific devices, from which you know the APNS device token.

Comment: @rckoenes https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html says Remote notifications and local notifications are not related to broadcast notifications or key-value observing notifications. I don't understand what they are...

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'Broadcast Notification' in iOS. There are only Remote and Local. Are these what you want to know about? If so your question is too broad and you need to do more research before coming back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast notifications refers to notifications sent using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/). You can use them to communicate between different objects within your process. On OS X there is also [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/) which can be used to send and receive messages between processes.

Remote notifications and local notifications are messages sent to the user. Either from a server (remote) or scheduled by an app on the same device (local).